# Respond to format.html with Javascript action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to execute some javascript on the respond_to action for format.html.

```
window.top.location.href='#{ @recurring_charge.confirmation_url }'
```

I need to execute javascript to open the window out of the iframe, otherwise I cannot render the page due to the following error message 'X-Frame-Options'to 'deny'.

How can I do this?

```
  def confirm_billing
    current_shop.with_shopify!
    @recurring_charge = RecurringCharge.new(recurring_charge_params)
    if @recurring_charge.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :js => "window.top.location.href='#{ @recurring_charge.confirmation_url }'" }
        format.json { render json: { success: true, redirect_url: @recurring_charge.confirmation_url }, status: 201 }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Something went wrong' }
        format.json { render json: { success: false, errors: @recurring_charge.errors.full_messages }, status: 201 }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: any reason why you're doing this clientside rather than just redirecting from the server?

Comment: the app is embedded in a shopify iframe so I'm limited on how I can redirect

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using render :text, can't believe it actually worked!

```
format.html { render :text => "<script>window.top.location.href='#{ @recurring_charge.confirmation_url }';</script>" }
```